# Printing each element in list on separate line

Tags: list, print, pretty-print

I am using `\n` so that when printing the list, each element in the list gets a new line when calling message.  I am trying to have a go at printing a list where each element does not have a `\n` at the end.  What commands would achieve printing each element in the list in a separate line?

```
(defvar hcom '("basic\n"))
(push "+ inix-frame\n" hcom)
(push "+ modust-launch\n" hcom)
(push "+ automode + speedbar\n" hcom)
(push "+ modelin + txscale\n" hcom)
(message "%s" (mapconcat #'identity (reverse hcom)))
```

Had a go with the following, but this makes an extra empty line between list elements.

```
(setq animals '(giraffe gazelle lion tiger))

(defun print-elements-of-list (list)
  "Print each element of LIST on a line of its own."
  (interactive)
  (while list
    (print (car list))
    (setq list (cdr list))))

(print-elements-of-list animals)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prin1` or `princ` for that (see [Elisp documentation on 'output functions'](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Functions.html))

```lisp
(dolist (animal '(giraffe gazelle lion tiger))
  (princ animal)
  (princ "\n"))
```

If you'd prefer to use `mapconcat`, then you can just pass the newline as separator:

```lisp
(mapconcat #'symbol-name '(giraffe gazelle lion tiger) "\n")
```

Comment: In what ways is `symbol-name` better than `identity`.  You are implying that  `symbol-name` is better, right?

Comment: `mapconcat` only works with strings while I have given it a list of symbols, for a list of strings `identity` would be the way to go...